# How to not have repeating elements in this Access-SQL server-Visual Basic 6 (ADO) Form (Master Detail)

Tags: sql-server, database, forms, ms-access, ado

As stated above I am using the internal Access visual basic 6 editor along with Microsft SQL server, what I want to function is not having repeated elements in the sub form which is in a table called Order details which has a relation to the main form called Orders.

What im getting is repeated information in the sub form, but all I want is the information to show according to the Order code or Id (Codigo Pedido)... and as you can see here that isn´t happening:

Form:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/63259070@N06/6871552418/

Code:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bn71VqxzB1W55sHcKMstCSxnIbmP5cyYWkBVnF1tzVs/edit

I don´t know what to do, should I use parameters, should I use SQL queries, should do some sort of looping structure... Im lost.., So if anyone could help me, even in the most minimal way I would seriously appreciate it

Comment: It is quite possible to post code in Satckoverflow, you can use the format button `{}` to make it look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the text property in MS Access, then you will not have to set focus:

```
 ''Me.ctCodigo.SetFocus
 Me.ctCodigo = rs.Fields(0).Value
```

If you must qualify, use .Value, which is available whether or not the control has focus.

I am not sure why you are not using linked tables, you do not mention an ADP, but if you must use ADO, consider binding the recordsets, it will make life easier: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998